# Using PIVOT function in Teradata SQL version 15.10.1.4

Tags: pivot-table, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to pivot the following table to make it a single record.
Example :

Table name - **ABC**

[image]

I know this can be done by case statement. But I have around millions of records for multiple item_id's , so I think using case statement would be very inefficient.

I expect the result to be like this -

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!